# Any way to find out which user has asked the most questions?

Tags: discussion, users

I am curious which user posted the most questions. Is there a way?

It is easy for reverse -- Jon Skeet!

Comment: I'm sure you and your sock-puppets rule the question-asking domain.  Of course you could just parse the data-dump.

Comment: @Lance Roberts I suggest you read the FAQ on what considered an offensive behavior on SO.

Answer (score 6):

As of the latest dump, it appears that [Masi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54964) has asked the most questions (770 now, 755 at the time of the dump)

[Here's the query I used](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104073). The empty name at the top is for community-owned community wiki posts.

Comment: Well, at least he's answered *some* questions... about 11% of how many he's asked, which is better than some of the other question-spawners. ;)

Comment: I don't get why people have a problem with other people asking questions, as long as they're not bad questions.  They have to come from somewhere.

Comment: Oh, and I saw this question and went to StackQL to look up the answer myself.  Since my shortcut takes me to the logs query first, I saw someone else was already working on it right away.  Nice to see it get used.  Now I just need to bug Jeff about a way to find out who asked all those community wiki questions.

Comment: @Joel - They can't _all_ be good questions, especially with that many. And check his most active tag: **`[beginner]`** for 424. Are _all 424_ of those beginner questions good questions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with beginner questions, either.

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for your answer! Is it possible to limit the query to output only the top 100 users? Thanks!